# correct usage with conjunctions

Tags: american-english, british-english

1. He was arrogant, dismissive of others work.
2. He was arrogant, a dismissive person allround.

Does 1. require an **and** conjunction as a **rule** or is ok as written? The second example sounds fine  with or without one.

Answer (score -1):

Depends what you want to convey, if his dismissiveness is a symptom of his arrogance I'd have said "He was arrogant; dismissive of others' work." if he's arrogant and also dismissive then you are listing individual faults in which case you do need an **and**. I'd phrase the second sentence as "He was arrogant, an all around dismissive person." but as far as I know that's just a personal preference for particular sentence structure rather than driven by any formal rule I was ever taught.

Comment: You need an apostrophe after _others_, and _all round_ is two words.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks, that's the problem with copy-paste and minimal edits, you miss what the spellcheck doesn't catch.